# Can I fix 6 pin volume potentiometer by connecting the Right & Left outputs?

Tags: potentiometer, volume

I have a Logitech Z533 speaker system with a 'scratchy' volume control on left channel.  Upon examination of the volume control board in the volume puck that sits on your desk, it is a 6 pin pot with single shaft.  From research I did, this is called a 6 pin dual gang rotary pot.

It is similar to this [image: Text]

Can I just connect (via a soldered wire) the middle pin output of Left and Right channels together to eliminate the 'scratchy' noise when adjusting the volume?  I think that would be easier than replacing it.

I tried to blow out the pot with compressed air but that had no effect.

Thanks for helping with my first question!

Comment: Connect the middle pins to what? To each other? Are you hoping that it will still work as a volume control after this modification? You just need contact cleaner spray - not compressed air.

Comment: Yes, connect the 2 middle pins together.  Since there is only one shaft, make the outputs same by connecting them.  That would eliminate the intermittent connection caused by the wiper contact no?

Comment: No. If you do that you'll destroy the stereo image and get the same audio on both stereo channels. If one is scratchy then you'll hear it from both speakers.

Comment: Ok, thank you Transistor!  I will order some contact cleaner and try it.

Comment: If a coupling capacitor is leaky and puts DC on the control then it will make a scratchy noise. Then the capacitor needs to be replaced.